# spring bind date field of command object

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a form that inserts/updates data. The command object (Bean) class has a Date field that is placed in the form as follows:

```
<form:hidden path="createdDate">
```

when I submit the form, the BindResult.hasErrors() is validated as true.

I think I need to bind the date object, but how is it done for Command object field?

The form bean code is as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")

public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="EmployeeName")
    private String employeeName;

    @Column(name="CreatedDate")
    private Date createdDate;

    //Setter and getter methods 
}
```

Error:

```
[Field error in object 'employee' on field 'CreatedDate': rejected value [Mon Sep 17 20:35:26 IST 2012]; codes [typeMismatch.employee.CreatedDate,typeMismatch.CreatedDate,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [subject.CreatedDate,CreatedDate]; arguments []; default message [CreatedDate]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'CreatedDate'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Date] for property 'CreatedDate': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]]
```

Comment: Can you show your command class content where you have defined the field createdDate? And also let me know which database you are using.

Comment: the comannd class/(form bean) is the hibernate mapping class that connects to mysql database

Comment: I need to see that class to answer your question. Please put that code here.

Answer (score 2):

Add this annotation to your date fields:

```
@Column(name="CreatedDate")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss") //whatever format is appropriate to you..
private Date createdDate;
```

Ensure that you have joda time as a dependency and the library is present in classpath. It will automatically register a converter to take care of the transformation.

Comment: FYI - hh (lowercase) is 12 hr time. HH (uppercase) is 24 hr time

Answer (score 0):

I found your problem. In your Employee model class the createdDate field is not defined correctly.
You need to use the @Temporal annotation to define that the field is of type date.

Please put the following annotation also on top of the field declaration of createdDate

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
```

I think this should solve your problem. Cheers.

Comment: Which database you are using?? Also let me know the datatype of the field createdDate in database.

Comment: Database :Mysql and datatype of createdDate is datetime

Comment: Ok. In that case everything seems good. In which format you are tryting to store the date in database? I think you need to convert this date to an accepted format by mysql before inserting.